# Change the color of part of line in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to change part of a line in a time series in ggplot.

- Desired output

I just want a section of the line to be red (I drew this on so ignore that you can still see black).

[image]

- Current output

[image]

- Current code

```
fin_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = `Distance`)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Mn), size = 1.5, alpha = 1, color = "black", linetype = "solid" ) +
  theme_bw() + labs(y="", x= "") +   
  theme_classic() + theme(text=element_text(size=36,  family="serif", face = "bold", color = "black")) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 450),labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1)) + theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = 'black', size = 1.5)) + theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1.5)) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3), labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1))+ theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(.3, "cm")) + coord_capped_cart(bottom='right', left='none', gap = 0.15) 
fin_plot
```

```
    data <- structure(list(Mg = c(0.903247645, 0.912560748, 0.896003508, 
                              0.909572697, 0.883631829, 0.905722594, 0.892465355, 0.909271173, 
                              0.880506202, 0.889278401, 0.878534542, 0.959209459, 0.913303825, 
                              0.929893977, 0.97778374, 0.9885554, 0.929716333, 1.028422583, 
                              1.025638955, 1.011352651, 1.041343955, 1.092562951, 1.129761801, 
                              1.088857171, 1.107257284, 1.116728405, 1.103053734, 1.041662037, 
                              1.134182243, 1.104550315, 1.086952767, 1.106004784, 1.057688595, 
                              1.034347579, 1.04641385, 1.139270945, 1.048446018, 1.033827731, 
                              1.075554754, 1.029893202, 1.074749532, 1.001626205, 0.977053541, 
                              0.987467665, 0.999540478, 0.945184816, 0.959677178, 0.962807712, 
                              0.967023936, 1.024286493, 0.881264816, 0.967181342, 1.000316876, 
                              0.956168258, 1.003214572, 1.00047837, 0.940103474, 0.929875987, 
                              0.928227112, 0.982410241, 0.983035162, 0.976666772, 1.019755049, 
                              1.075189042, 0.975380543, 0.981316782, 0.986876269, 1.026690916, 
                              1.052379934, 1.001547298, 0.979888683, 1.008209647, 0.976098272, 
                              0.944479556, 0.996767684, 1.018077758, 1.028862706, 1.08510417, 
                              1.08963868, 1.048481179, 1.139954126, 1.107066353, 1.122920581, 
                              1.23904326, 1.19449336, 1.179971969, 1.165865352, 1.068804094, 
                              1.099436469, 1.073307737, 1.07045113, 1.101007051, 1.011962649, 
                              1.11202545, 1.097883672, 1.05361424, 0.993283703, 1.046635444, 
                              1.04951188, 1.055736151, 1.063705172, 0.977095039, 1.015650848, 
                              1.029367222, 1.003814349, 0.973376993, 1.021665177, 0.925511352, 
                              1.014703757, 0.933654542, 1.027336075, 0.961163947, 1.022921765, 
                              0.910164297, 0.937410814, 0.935246588, 0.925900983, 0.934477753, 
                              0.927973832, 0.946372309, 0.950554394, 0.9386026, 1.000712639, 
                              0.947846812, 0.953585987, 0.967735737, 0.927914753, 0.943303715, 
                              0.935435884, 0.987648375, 0.902379461, 0.939086878, 1.018529942, 
                              0.973874968, 0.974093087, 0.984149676, 0.948669001, 0.934863295, 
                              1.011232041, 0.942884239, 0.978044788, 1.023700208, 1.011714275, 
                              0.999153709, 1.06822476, 0.967735328, 1.131133479, 1.011068503, 
                              1.034903609, 1.078701437, 1.049655794, 1.097777577, 1.06172881, 
                              1.197399846, 1.079896085, 1.186101797, 1.199388268, 1.15701997, 
                              1.089004764, 1.115041506, 1.154124932, 1.133278285, 1.096056948, 
                              1.131271873, 1.116672802, 1.078030317, 1.040967817, 1.053747728, 
                              1.100372522, 1.133677114, 1.223971358, 1.117169754, 1.084546095, 
                              1.047035909, 1.030681048, 1.076345258, 1.122537084, 1.072586737, 
                              1.047181662, 1.039218365, 1.068698816, 1.128110676, 1.006461218, 
                              1.093800528, 1.052872185, 1.048359752, 1.07256098, 1.011260865, 
                              1.071809317, 1.037520223, 1.074106418, 1.05109023, 1.03030123, 
                              1.044579971, 0.997926967, 1.00759045, 1.025063505, 1.028076086, 
                              0.9757945), Mn = c(0.086720869, 0.113119382, 0.088197332, 0.081547788, 
                                                 0.079373211, 0.07888827, 0.072865285, 0.079637996, 0.066314774, 
                                                 0.097585729, 0.185034982, 0.214466904, 0.294317625, 0.481389256, 
                                                 0.531196058, 0.715842439, 0.865098887, 0.987242052, 1.081028291, 
                                                 1.240920518, 1.313524957, 1.543771699, 1.78495042, 1.746572555, 
                                                 2.048760527, 2.101438775, 1.967474033, 2.000286925, 2.014020838, 
                                                 1.924470659, 1.75696549, 1.786681246, 1.633290961, 1.455799758, 
                                                 1.315346538, 1.435348984, 1.27887702, 1.152818928, 1.095127218, 
                                                 0.987502349, 1.062278922, 0.898540082, 0.83617998, 0.889057689, 
                                                 0.825563648, 0.788347646, 0.790973555, 0.775541228, 0.815063004, 
                                                 0.848723108, 0.66783059, 0.672629631, 0.747809615, 0.72338158, 
                                                 0.666220438, 0.664051795, 0.597260657, 0.689282162, 0.663808452, 
                                                 0.678551141, 0.672917354, 0.686199986, 0.724202364, 0.746195474, 
                                                 0.686135659, 0.654148537, 0.713488795, 0.72446665, 0.699529989, 
                                                 0.630120423, 0.661767463, 0.663290351, 0.705879842, 0.709399338, 
                                                 0.76228353, 0.714368918, 0.720561695, 0.837036666, 0.923882149, 
                                                 1.014163852, 1.221410703, 1.315825246, 1.368054705, 1.641746627, 
                                                 1.630198312, 1.698589629, 1.562956393, 1.427322658, 1.53964983, 
                                                 1.574583495, 1.527101216, 1.380123116, 1.28649445, 1.29251968, 
                                                 1.330565441, 1.317758525, 1.19292313, 1.217953538, 1.218591815, 
                                                 1.163372928, 1.091026791, 0.878691182, 0.903966928, 0.917620557, 
                                                 0.838430901, 0.825709255, 0.839298558, 0.76309434, 0.97617394, 
                                                 0.739885015, 0.822159341, 0.785335779, 0.771926988, 0.766619321, 
                                                 0.832448556, 0.733734124, 0.787221188, 0.685452005, 0.740552711, 
                                                 0.707414697, 0.781271754, 0.72652958, 0.729470139, 0.71649368, 
                                                 0.681176551, 0.683977986, 0.711079301, 0.681092777, 0.747615639, 
                                                 0.700953146, 0.692246657, 0.673560118, 0.820384633, 0.740567172, 
                                                 0.72070082, 0.795192662, 0.773897168, 0.74552279, 0.735710787, 
                                                 0.768825863, 0.746016457, 0.736542042, 0.744507532, 0.784312542, 
                                                 0.758393534, 0.7600356, 0.797384742, 0.773626898, 0.744557896, 
                                                 0.855000158, 0.867564728, 0.870754116, 0.891695067, 1.050643841, 
                                                 1.086358398, 1.217041501, 1.373025781, 1.492662215, 1.563662984, 
                                                 1.834762408, 1.877449635, 1.766642359, 1.731492777, 1.728551719, 
                                                 1.947777721, 1.951293228, 1.918622452, 1.979387861, 1.922875966, 
                                                 2.150308307, 1.863476368, 1.836654797, 1.841008541, 1.517006974, 
                                                 1.721636892, 1.537470714, 1.590262156, 1.505842124, 1.398523427, 
                                                 1.180718089, 1.330067785, 1.264569656, 1.174501376, 1.116396782, 
                                                 1.205453294, 1.193128576, 1.199711798, 1.18175828, 1.14051266, 
                                                 1.107141774, 1.028976851, 1.101895442, 0.933531591, 0.985243449, 
                                                 0.883647299, 0.871531516, 0.791794339, 0.82156345, 0.734425258
                              ), Zn = c(0.746612627, 0.818368055, 0.696689824, 0.748702805, 
                                        0.717457681, 0.766243608, 0.805305259, 0.855909762, 0.803357905, 
                                        0.889646097, 0.854456208, 1.067795473, 1.051422575, 1.17061972, 
                                        1.138440648, 1.052796919, 1.040998633, 1.161739158, 1.025956799, 
                                        0.971567748, 1.072911493, 0.952121155, 1.040392714, 1.069745522, 
                                        1.068549198, 1.090194087, 1.214584829, 1.157485471, 1.245813376, 
                                        1.336359991, 1.204038397, 1.126255292, 1.131057736, 0.922042386, 
                                        1.037566449, 1.100852394, 1.121842367, 0.998657748, 1.006938923, 
                                        1.002800377, 0.897387497, 0.93902937, 0.889327622, 0.802133735, 
                                        0.855245047, 0.860702407, 0.704324249, 0.905827093, 0.760155095, 
                                        0.760247698, 0.655991619, 0.677006743, 0.668001976, 0.623410532, 
                                        0.569302474, 0.523713794, 0.690042836, 0.539115342, 0.528696218, 
                                        0.57851915, 0.60294784, 0.581392042, 0.65277069, 0.65620614, 
                                        0.625397246, 0.697647782, 0.6180657, 0.632326126, 0.684659215, 
                                        0.606197513, 0.630134281, 0.637151517, 0.574538208, 0.605993607, 
                                        0.533522181, 0.544522236, 0.577535469, 0.573427383, 0.672984155, 
                                        0.735286828, 0.7532343, 0.881292245, 0.801132661, 1.122761046, 
                                        1.137397845, 1.173190388, 1.138033979, 1.126494557, 1.144871399, 
                                        1.087042815, 0.981750792, 0.992888445, 0.955352455, 1.074357698, 
                                        1.027127808, 1.083248059, 1.010304962, 1.037776316, 1.052809984, 
                                        0.959161909, 0.939369893, 0.932304641, 0.912110856, 1.035278327, 
                                        0.825391661, 0.883818816, 0.880397247, 0.775385156, 0.860535004, 
                                        0.75878312, 0.764243502, 0.788209749, 0.736029937, 0.746966542, 
                                        0.762295984, 0.804665042, 0.797845669, 0.744225613, 0.846139103, 
                                        0.806957411, 0.789078125, 0.912631032, 0.926629248, 0.807376002, 
                                        0.795165332, 0.776764645, 0.811532921, 0.740169463, 0.707007363, 
                                        0.764252403, 0.754265833, 0.656183602, 0.78602999, 0.734580057, 
                                        0.756587437, 0.750509131, 0.727536118, 0.676232276, 0.714439923, 
                                        0.720668076, 0.763533465, 0.60234143, 0.651920197, 0.744086872, 
                                        0.633919728, 0.615213712, 0.705944962, 0.667362984, 0.742636421, 
                                        0.748062261, 0.718290208, 0.866047893, 0.754624731, 0.753850346, 
                                        0.723216532, 0.874448292, 0.967358157, 1.102255319, 1.225145961, 
                                        1.375482642, 1.508302364, 1.452575717, 1.456946995, 1.477964732, 
                                        1.711047017, 1.662721246, 1.539275314, 1.595349018, 1.699728078, 
                                        1.849605828, 1.688668818, 1.819401302, 1.972652441, 1.876873848, 
                                        1.920264068, 2.061536452, 2.00629895, 1.959281378, 1.956005981, 
                                        1.841888926, 1.929803629, 1.669570099, 1.596624552, 1.654602575, 
                                        1.433160972, 1.487724776, 1.457591295, 1.558387099, 1.505276849, 
                                        1.389005594, 1.538544454, 1.296637953, 1.343107585, 1.27500613, 
                                        1.181323757, 1.181523008, 1.309586833, 1.148849891, 1.129687476
                              ), Ba = c(0.742734852, 0.839492568, 0.743899849, 0.817080816, 
                                        0.773569657, 0.735728339, 0.715168283, 0.78077814, 0.694280484, 
                                        0.773303425, 0.768041196, 0.883401699, 0.818274274, 0.715927964, 
                                        0.696938222, 0.832246446, 0.73089346, 0.790965216, 0.799717389, 
                                        0.865896893, 0.946771069, 0.954212275, 1.023740345, 1.027036123, 
                                        1.086336263, 1.064542815, 0.9463809, 0.924081609, 0.999832641, 
                                        0.911277648, 0.922871168, 0.953134033, 0.786732115, 0.802026729, 
                                        0.832863371, 0.863952475, 0.817833153, 0.748586924, 0.72095701, 
                                        0.738213943, 0.672736744, 0.704947698, 0.531743532, 0.634123809, 
                                        0.683548549, 0.733277161, 0.608993729, 0.752162246, 0.568705823, 
                                        0.643172511, 0.597251486, 0.655514695, 0.583437677, 0.557676441, 
                                        0.646713866, 0.527005047, 0.578023512, 0.576281064, 0.600923204, 
                                        0.578475648, 0.551957027, 0.585007991, 0.623858699, 0.630936819, 
                                        0.636198589, 0.565476603, 0.658861425, 0.577557604, 0.629178306, 
                                        0.646092809, 0.566079299, 0.60953767, 0.680135261, 0.500802233, 
                                        0.704656678, 0.61109605, 0.645344144, 0.667139888, 0.734969576, 
                                        0.780062983, 0.783090234, 0.83005691, 0.905356723, 0.933746319, 
                                        0.947613375, 0.923115827, 0.873482691, 0.746883952, 0.850273618, 
                                        0.795256154, 0.800825928, 0.772630039, 0.749567395, 0.7823457, 
                                        0.772609842, 0.736269985, 0.699705666, 0.716860238, 0.65909369, 
                                        0.806743181, 0.604632102, 0.629103485, 0.669824708, 0.545219042, 
                                        0.605081484, 0.545598194, 0.612458887, 0.640840679, 0.568115521, 
                                        0.578270006, 0.642784637, 0.486235168, 0.608704086, 0.449107996, 
                                        0.603056279, 0.573624703, 0.527880861, 0.479058818, 0.608581986, 
                                        0.497792884, 0.736359035, 0.560758315, 0.59150912, 0.491623628, 
                                        0.646548159, 0.559243084, 0.554057512, 0.542344646, 0.583808567, 
                                        0.623315676, 0.521008383, 0.511710892, 0.633820855, 0.529775704, 
                                        0.590383598, 0.500021436, 0.602344336, 0.499887402, 0.534870849, 
                                        0.583225149, 0.623554367, 0.62596102, 0.585378422, 0.648988779, 
                                        0.577416685, 0.632021029, 0.644454559, 0.684966009, 0.595845502, 
                                        0.738800574, 0.699692813, 0.735600272, 0.916889652, 0.957440119, 
                                        0.940642207, 0.982945679, 1.040869211, 0.968988195, 1.202672647, 
                                        1.125246185, 1.072149728, 1.163386327, 1.082737071, 0.957718286, 
                                        1.073014525, 1.200702065, 1.062026456, 1.027530031, 1.066130572, 
                                        1.039337914, 0.970167423, 1.134895746, 1.013487628, 0.824278282, 
                                        0.843864753, 1.05735407, 1.112876459, 0.962913956, 0.90808515, 
                                        0.871953689, 0.993060229, 0.869462576, 0.949186443, 0.989669433, 
                                        0.764506726, 0.755280383, 0.870762986, 0.941377101, 0.837105653, 
                                        0.946608575, 0.921411019, 0.937765975, 0.908506991, 0.810663688, 
                                        0.848783174, 0.856162412, 0.913266132, 0.848558712, 0.878929447
                              ), All = c(2.479315993, 2.683540753, 2.424790513, 2.556904106, 
                                         2.454032378, 2.486582811, 2.485804182, 2.625597071, 2.444459365, 
                                         2.649813652, 2.686066928, 3.124873535, 3.077318299, 3.297830917, 
                                         3.344358668, 3.589441204, 3.566707313, 3.968369009, 3.932341434, 
                                         4.08973781, 4.374551474, 4.54266808, 4.97884528, 4.932211371, 
                                         5.310903272, 5.372904082, 5.231493496, 5.123516042, 5.393849098, 
                                         5.276658613, 4.970827822, 4.972075355, 4.608769407, 4.214216452, 
                                         4.232190208, 4.539424798, 4.266998558, 3.933891331, 3.898577905, 
                                         3.758409871, 3.707152695, 3.544143355, 3.234304675, 3.312782898, 
                                         3.363897722, 3.32751203, 3.063968711, 3.396338279, 3.110947858, 
                                         3.27642981, 2.802338511, 2.972332411, 2.999566144, 2.860636811, 
                                         2.88545135, 2.715249006, 2.805430479, 2.734554555, 2.721654986, 
                                         2.81795618, 2.810857383, 2.829266791, 3.020586802, 3.108527475, 
                                         2.923112037, 2.898589704, 2.977292189, 2.961041296, 3.065747444, 
                                         2.883958043, 2.837869726, 2.918189185, 2.936651583, 2.760674734, 
                                         2.997230073, 2.888064962, 2.972304014, 3.162708107, 3.42147456, 
                                         3.577994842, 3.897689363, 4.134240754, 4.19746467, 4.937297252, 
                                         4.909702892, 4.974867813, 4.740338415, 4.369505261, 4.634231316, 
                                         4.530190201, 4.380129066, 4.246648651, 4.003376949, 4.261248528, 
                                         4.228186763, 4.190890809, 3.896217461, 4.019225536, 3.980007369, 
                                         3.985014169, 3.698733958, 3.417194347, 3.50155334, 3.527485148, 
                                         3.272718395, 3.228503258, 3.353819869, 3.104831527, 3.419528222, 
                                         3.010592683, 3.256523555, 3.020944643, 3.139582776, 2.872858156, 
                                         3.135211633, 3.047270457, 3.038848701, 2.843214189, 3.123247632, 
                                         2.958537301, 3.257263308, 3.138521527, 3.248321146, 2.963340122, 
                                         3.076476029, 2.987721452, 3.004584487, 2.906910601, 2.973867453, 
                                         3.0761696, 2.869900334, 2.78054149, 3.25876542, 2.978797901, 
                                         3.041764942, 3.029872905, 3.052446623, 2.856505763, 2.9962536, 
                                         3.015603327, 3.111149077, 2.9885447, 2.993520426, 3.176541902, 
                                         3.037954707, 2.975005669, 3.278917742, 3.137024394, 3.117943428, 
                                         3.42056443, 3.335203543, 3.570179858, 3.62493826, 3.959334152, 
                                         3.830113222, 4.260537269, 4.580641417, 4.720925699, 5.080486356, 
                                         5.450532741, 5.612026659, 5.515882688, 5.367233791, 5.29550661, 
                                         5.848512065, 5.892746856, 5.560892039, 5.656014638, 5.789107138, 
                                         6.172929163, 5.746283967, 5.908121599, 5.911694705, 5.265195013, 
                                         5.516446761, 5.732706494, 5.831974649, 5.500624195, 5.30979622, 
                                         4.933779069, 5.321630459, 4.931713007, 4.726773589, 4.854469318, 
                                         4.455993177, 4.484493487, 4.600627059, 4.692783345, 4.554704479, 
                                         4.480276166, 4.563038742, 4.3873896, 4.215447397, 4.115493238, 
                                         3.911681197, 3.916807386, 4.039710809, 3.847048139, 3.718836681
                              ), Distance = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
                                              15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
                                              31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
                                              47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 
                                              63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 
                                              79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 
                                              95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 
                                              109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 
                                              122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 
                                              135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 
                                              148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 
                                              161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 
                                              174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 
                                              187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199
                              )), row.names = c(NA, -199L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                              ), na.action = structure(c(`18435` = 18435L, `18457` = 18457L, 
                                                         `18458` = 18458L, `18459` = 18459L, `18460` = 18460L, `18515` = 18515L, 
                                                         `18868` = 18868L, `18869` = 18869L, `18870` = 18870L, `19173` = 19173L, 
                                                         `19174` = 19174L, `19293` = 19293L, `19417` = 19417L, `19418` = 19418L, 
                                                         `19419` = 19419L, `19420` = 19420L, `20062` = 20062L, `20063` = 20063L, 
                                                         `20064` = 20064L, `20065` = 20065L, `20066` = 20066L, `20237` = 20237L, 
                                                         `20238` = 20238L, `20239` = 20239L), class = "omit"))
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to use a second `geom_line` for which you use only the data you want to highlight:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = Distance)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Mn), size = 1.5, alpha = 1, color = "black", linetype = "solid") +
  geom_line(data = ~subset(.x, Distance > 40 & Distance < 60), aes(y = Mn), size = 1.5, alpha = 1, color = "red", linetype = "solid") +
  labs(y = "", x = "") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 36, family = "serif", face = "bold", color = "black")) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 1)) +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1.5)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = "black", size = 1.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3), labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(.3, "cm"))
```

[image]